# using ObjectAL with spritekit causes SKAction sounds not to be found?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, openal, skaction

I'm trying to use both ObjectAL and native SKAction in my spritekit project.

I've got it working, but when i run this code,

```
OALSimpleAudio.sharedInstance().playBg("shipengine.wav", loop:true)
```

it gives me an error saying `'Resource powershotbeep.wav can not be loaded'`  this is a file I use with SKAction somewhere else in the project.  any idea why this would be happening?

if i stop loading those actions, then my shipengine sound will play just fine

i've tried this with objective-c as well.. i get this error

2014-09-06 13:18:23.790 testsound[59331:4033724] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper openDevice:]: Could not open device (null)
2014-09-06 13:18:23.791 testsound[59331:4033724] OAL Error: -[ALDevice initWithDeviceSpecifier:]: : Failed to create OpenAL device (null)
2014-09-06 13:18:23.791 testsound[59331:4033724] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper closeDevice:]: Invalid Enum (error code 0x0000a003)
2014-09-06 13:18:23.791 testsound[59331:4033724] OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification, but last reset was 0.001220 seconds ago. Doing nothing.
2014-09-06 13:18:23.791 testsound[59331:4033724] OAL Error: -[OALSimpleAudio initWithSources:]: : Could not create OpenAL device

Comment: sk actions and playbg (but not playeffect) of objectal use avaudioplayer, that might explain it. stick to using only one audio engine.